# Como evitar envió de datos si no cumple alguna validación con php

Tags: php, validación

Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar con una duda que por mas que eh investigado no doy con la solución, tengo un formulario y mi validación de campos con php, al pulsar en el botón "submit" sin valores en los campos me muestra error de que los campos están vacíos, hasta ahí todo bien, pero por ejemplo tengo otra validación que indica que el campo nombre solo acepta letras y espacios en blanco, al ingresar un valor numérico y pulsar en el botón de enviar me manda los datos y después me muestra el mensaje de error de que solo se aceptan letras y espacios en blanco, lo que quiero es que al pulsar en el botón de envió me muestre la validación y no me envié nada, se que esto se logra con javascript de echo mis validaciones del lado del cliente ya las tengo y esto que quiero si lo hace con javascript pero no consigo hacerlo con php ya que quiero evitar envió de datos basura a mi base de datos, espero me puedan auxiliar, de ante mano muchas gracias :)
MI CÓDIGO PHP CON LAS VALIDACIONES ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
<?php
            //Definir variables para mensajes de error y establecer valores vacios
            $nombreErr = $emailErr = $websiteErr = $generoErr = "";

            //Recoger valores de campos de entrada
            //Si el boton de envio "submit" ha sido seleccionado (clickeado) y el metodod de envio es mediante "Post"
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $nombre = test_input($_POST['nombre']);
                $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
                $website = test_input($_POST['website']);

                if (empty($nombre) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){//Si el campo nombre esta vacio se muestra el siguiente mensaje de error 
                    $nombreErr = "Nombre requerido";    
                }else{
                    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zñA-ZÑ]*$/", $nombre)){
                    $nombreErr= "Solo se admiten letras y espacios en blanco";
                    }
                }

                if(empty($email)){
                    $emailErr = "Email requerido";
                }else{
                    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    $emailErr = "Formato de correo no valido";
                    }
                }

                if(empty($website)){
                    $website = " ";
                }else{
                    //Comprobar si la sintaxis de la direccion URL es valida
                    if(!preg_match("/\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.[-a-a0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $website)){
                    $websiteErr = "URL invalido";
                    }
                }
            }

            //La función analiza los datos insertados eliminando carácteres inecesarios como barras invertidas, espacios, etc
            function test_input($data){
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }
        ?>
```

MI CÓDIGO DEL FORMULARIO EL SIGUIENTE:

### EJEMPLO DE VALIDACIÓN DE FORMULARIO

```
    <p><span class="error"> * Campos requeridos</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($nombre)) echo $nombre?>">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $nombreErr;?></span>
        </br></br>
        E-mail:<input type="text" name="email">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        </br></br>
        Website:<input type="text" name="website">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Y EN ESTA PARTE DE CODIGO PHP MUESTRO LOS VALORES INGRESADOS POR EL USUARIO:

```
   <?php
        echo "<h2>Sus datos son:</h2>";
        echo $nombre;
        echo "</br>";
        echo $email;
        echo "</br>";
        echo $website;
        echo "</br>";
        echo $coment;
        echo "</br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta es confusa.. podrias mostrar lo que tenes y aclarar donde esta el problema?

Comment: Podés hacerlo de ambas formas, desde javascript y adicional desde php, podrías colocar tu código?

Comment: @LudOsorio eh editado mi publicación para ingresar mi código, ojala me puedas apoyar, gracias

Comment: Hola @Dianely Te sugiero hacer un pequeño archivo de código javaScript que haga validaciones de formato para los campos y anexarlo a tu código. Para aprender ha hacerlo puedes leer [Expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Hola @quevedo de echo ya tengo mi validacion con javascript, lo que quiero es que cuando se ingrese un valor no valido, al pulsar el boton de envio no me mande nada, por ejemplo en mi codigo, al cargar el formulario y si no se ingresa nada y se da click en enviar me muestra el mensaje de que los campos no deben  estan vacios, ingreso por ejemplo el nombre y si el valor ingresado son numeros y pulso el boton de envio me manda los datos y despues me muestra el mensaje de que el campo solo acepta letras y espacios en blanco, no se si me explico.

Comment: @quevedo de echo en javascript esto se logra con un return false si el dato no es valido pero quiero hacerlo con php puesto que la validación con  javascript podría evitarse o el navegador podría tener desactivado javascript  si no logro evitar con php esto me mandaría datos basura a la base de datos, saludos.

Comment: @Dianely los elementos form tienen un evento **onsubmit** en el puedes llamar al método de validación y en caso de error de formato devolver 0 y mostrar un **mensaje de reclamo** `<form ... onsubmit="tuMetodo()" ...>`

Comment: @quevedo pero eso se hace con javascript, ya hace eso mi codigo de javascript, cree una funcion que llama al formulario como me indicas pero yo quiero hacer lo que te explico con php por si llegara a fallar la validacion de javascript

Comment: @Dianely la variable `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` indica que estás enviando el formulario a la página que lo sirve. ¿Hay en ella alguna función que procese el envío antes de servirla?

Comment: @quevedo tengo entendido que esa variable global envía los datos del formulario a la misma pagina en vez de mandarlos a otra, de esta manera el usuario recibirá los mensajes de error en la misma pagina, entonces ¿tendría que crear una función que la llame como me dices?, me podrías proporcionar un ejemplo para entender mejor ya que no tengo ninguna función que lo haga, gracias.

Comment: @Dianely si, y además debe establecer si hubo o no post para diferenciar si está sirviendo la página por primera vez o está respondiendo al mismo.